# Debug java plugin

Tags: java, debugging, applet

Is it possible to debug the applet loading process of the java plugin?

I don't want to debug my applet application, I want to debug the applet loading process of the java plugin2. I mean the jnlp/jar download, cache lookup, certificate check, etc. I know the java plugin is not open source, but it would help anyway.

I'm trying to solve JNLP2ClassLoader issues happening only within IE. It works with Google Chrome or Firefox. The error is not very reproducible, but one of the is "JNLP2ClassLoader.findClass: org.apache.log4j.spi.ThrowableInformation: try again...".

Comment: Do you mean how to debug it within a browser?

Comment: It might be helpful if you posted a stack trace to show what the issue is you are trying to debug.

Comment: Yes, debug within the browser, remote debug, whatever works. The error is not very reproducible, that's why I'm trying to debug.

Comment: Does this verifies with all the versions of the Java Plugin? Does it happen before 1.6.0_u14? Have you tried the update 18?

I have some issues using the updates between this versions in my applet launch sequence.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the log level to trace, pressing 5 anytime in the java plugin console. Configure the plugin to open the console automatically and press 5 as soon as it opens. this will print a bunch of stuff that can or cannot be useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

I know you can with eclipse if you put a breakpoint somewhere in one of the init methods.  You should be able to run an applet from your debugger without needing a webpage.